# Numpy Savetxt Overwriting, Cannot Figure Out Where to Place Loop

Tags: python, csv, numpy, for-loop, overwrite

I am creating a program that calculates correlations between my customer's data. I want to print the correlation values to a CSV so I can further analyze the data.

I have successfully gotten my program to loop through all the customers (12 months of data each) while calculating their individual correlations for multiple arrangements. I can see this if I print to the dialog.

However, when I try to save using Savetxt, I am only getting the final values I calculate.

I think I have placed my for loop in the wrong place, where should it go? I have tried checking out other questions, but it didn't shed too much light onto it.

EDIT: I have attempted aligning the writing with both the outer for loop and the inner for loop as suggested, both yielded the same results.

```
for x_customer in range(0,len(overalldata),12):

        for x in range(0,13,1):
                cust_months = overalldata[0:x,1]
                cust_balancenormal = overalldata[0:x,16]
                cust_demo_one = overalldata[0:x,2]
                cust_demo_two = overalldata[0:x,3]
                num_acct_A = overalldata[0:x,4]
                num_acct_B = overalldata[0:x,5]
    #Correlation Calculations
                demo_one_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
                demo_one_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_one_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_two)[1,0]

                result_correlation = [(demo_one_corr_balance),(demo_two_corr_balance),(demo_one_corr_acct_a),(demo_one_corr_acct_b),(demo_two_corr_acct_a),(demo_two_corr_acct_b)]

        result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append([result_correlation])
        cust_delete_list = [0,(x_customer),1]
        overalldata = numpy.delete(overalldata, (cust_delete_list), axis=0)

numpy.savetxt('correlationoutput.csv', numpy.column_stack(result_correlation), delimiter=',')
print result_correlation
```

Comment: you hypothesis sounds right. you should unindent the last `savetxt` line

Comment: It is throwing an "unexpected indent error"

Comment: no indent at all should do it (aligned with the outer `for`)

Comment: I attempted just that solution, but it did not work.

Comment: can you edit your question with the newly indented code & explaining that?

Comment: Sure thing, I have added the edits. Thank you.

Comment: must be a problem with you editor and TABS/spaces. Which one are you using?Try copying/pasting your code from this question to your code.

Comment: hpaulj, I have attempted to do this with the result_correlation_combined. However it does not work correctly, I am getting a zero vector for this. Can you tell why this is occurring?

Comment: Jean-Francois, I have tried that, it is not the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of the code is just sloppy:

```
                result_correlation = [(demo_one_corr_balance),...]

        result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append([result_correlation])
        cust_delete_list = [0,(x_customer),1]
        overalldata = numpy.delete(overalldata, (cust_delete_list), axis=0)

numpy.savetxt('correlationoutput.csv', numpy.column_stack(result_correlation), delimiter=',')
print result_correlation
```

You set `result_correlation` in the inner most loop, and then you use it in the final save and print.  Obviously it will print the result of the last loop.

Meanwhile you append it to `result_correlation_combined`, outside of the `x` loop, near tend of the `x_customer` loop.  But you don't do anything with the list.

And finally in the `x_customer` loop you play with `overalldata`, but I don't see any further use.

Forget about the `savetxt` for now, and get the data collection straight.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I have upvoted you, it will display once my reputation is higher.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of the above poster and corrected my code. I am now able to write to a file. However, I am having trouble with the number of iterations complete, I will post that in a different question as it is unrelated. Here is the solution that I used.

```
for x_customer in range(0,len(overalldata),12):

        for x in range(0,13,1):
                cust_months = overalldata[0:x,1]

                cust_balancenormal = overalldata[0:x,16]

                cust_demo_one = overalldata[0:x,2]
                cust_demo_two = overalldata[0:x,3]

                num_acct_A = overalldata[0:x,4]
                num_acct_B = overalldata[0:x,5]

                out_mark_channel_one = overalldata[0:x,25]
                out_service_channel_two = overalldata[0:x,26]
                out_mark_channel_three = overalldata[0:x,27]
                out_mark_channel_four = overalldata[0:x,28]


    #Correlation Calculations

                #Demographic to Balance Correlations
                demo_one_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, cust_demo_two)[1,0]


                #Demographic to Account Number Correlations
                demo_one_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_one_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_one)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, cust_demo_two)[1,0]
                demo_two_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, cust_demo_two)[1,0]

                #Marketing Response Channel One
                mark_one_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, out_mark_channel_one)[1, 0]
                mark_one_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, out_mark_channel_one)[1, 0]
                mark_one_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, out_mark_channel_one)[1, 0]

                #Marketing Response Channel Two
                mark_two_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, out_service_channel_two)[1, 0]
                mark_two_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, out_service_channel_two)[1, 0]
                mark_two_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, out_service_channel_two)[1, 0]

                #Marketing Response Channel Three
                mark_three_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, out_mark_channel_three)[1, 0]
                mark_three_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, out_mark_channel_three)[1, 0]
                mark_three_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, out_mark_channel_three)[1, 0]

                #Marketing Response Channel Four
                mark_four_corr_acct_a = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_A, out_mark_channel_four)[1, 0]
                mark_four_corr_acct_b = numpy.corrcoef(num_acct_B, out_mark_channel_four)[1, 0]
                mark_four_corr_balance = numpy.corrcoef(cust_balancenormal, out_mark_channel_four)[1, 0]


                #Result Correlations For Exporting to CSV of all Correlations
                result_correlation = [(demo_one_corr_balance),(demo_two_corr_balance),(demo_one_corr_acct_a),(demo_one_corr_acct_b),(demo_two_corr_acct_a),(demo_two_corr_acct_b),(mark_one_corr_acct_a),(mark_one_corr_acct_b),(mark_one_corr_balance),
                                      (mark_two_corr_acct_a),(mark_two_corr_acct_b),(mark_two_corr_balance),(mark_three_corr_acct_a),(mark_three_corr_acct_b),(mark_three_corr_balance),(mark_four_corr_acct_a),(mark_four_corr_acct_b),
                                      (mark_four_corr_balance)]
                result_correlation_nan_nuetralized = numpy.nan_to_num(result_correlation)
                c.writerow(result_correlation)

        result_correlation_combined = emptylist.append([result_correlation])
        cust_delete_list = [0,x_customer,1]
        overalldata = numpy.delete(overalldata, (cust_delete_list), axis=0)
```